# No puedo cerrar la ventana de Tkinter de una función python

Tags: python-3.x

No puedo cerrar la ventana que puse dentro de una función de mi código, ya intente poner todas las funciones de ventana en una misma función para cerrar la ventana pero no se puede. Al abrir la ventana con función alegre1, no me cierra la función de ventana alegre, pero si se cierra la ventana principal de tk. Aquí dejo el código:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *


ventana1 = Tk()
ventana1.geometry("500x500")
ventana1.title("Interación")
label = Label(ventana1, text ="¿Como estas hoy?")
label.pack(pady = 10) 

def alegre():
  nueva = Toplevel(ventana1)
  nueva.title("Interación")
  nueva.geometry("500x500")
  Label(nueva, text ="Te pondre música alegre").pack()
  boton1 = Button(nueva, text ="Más", command = alegre1)
  boton1.place(x = 210, y = 40)
  ventana1.withdraw()

def alegre1():
  nueva1 = Toplevel(nueva)
  nueva1.title("Interación")
  nueva1.geometry("500x500")
  Label(nueva1, text ="¿Como quieres seguir?").pack()
  boton1 = Button(nueva1, text ="Karaoke", command = karaoke)
  boton1.place(x = 210, y = 40)
  boton1 = Button(nueva1, text ="Videos graciosos", command = karaoke)
  boton1.place(x = 210, y = 70)
  nueva.withdraw()

def karaoke():
  nueva2 = Toplevel(ventana1)
  nueva2.title("Interación")
  nueva2.geometry("500x500")
  Label(nueva2, text ="Quieres cerrar").pack()
  boton1 = Button(nueva2, text ="cerrar", command = cerrar)
  boton1.place(x = 210, y = 40) 
  nueva1.withdraw()

def cerrar():
  nueva3 = Toplevel(ventana1)
  nueva3.title("Interación")
  nueva3.geometry("500x500")
  Label(nueva3, text ="Adios").pack()
  nueva2.withdraw() 

def triste():
  nueva4 = Toplevel(ventana1)
  nueva4.title("Interación")
  nueva4.geometry("500x500")
  Label(nueva4, text ="Te pondre música triste").pack()
  ventana1.withdraw()

boton1 = Button(ventana1, text ="Alegre", command = alegre)
boton1.place(x = 210, y = 40)
boton2 = Button(ventana1, text ="Triste", command = triste)
boton2.place(x = 210, y = 80)

mainloop()

input()
```

Aquí dejo como me imprime el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te cierra la ventana generada por el metodo alegre debido a que la variable nueva del metodo alegre y alegre1 son distintas. esto es porque al definir una variable en una funcion, esta existe solo para esa funcion y su contenido solo se puede usar dentro de la misma.

Para poder acceder a la variable `ventana` de la funcion `alegre()` debes emplear la nomenclatura del punto `alegre().ventana`  para posteriormente pasarlo como objeto a la funcion `alegre1()` o puedes usar programacion orientada a objetos(POO).

La solucion mas sencilla es pasarlo como objeto. pero usar programacion orientada a objetos te facilitara la vida, te recomiendo aprenderlo.

Entonces, la solucion es:

Aquí dejo el código:

```py
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
    
    
ventana1 = Tk()
ventana1.geometry("500x500")
ventana1.title("Interación")
label = Label(ventana1, text ="¿Como estas hoy?")
label.pack(pady = 10) 
    
def alegre():
      nueva = Toplevel(ventana1)
      nueva.title("Interación")
      nueva.geometry("500x500")
      Label(nueva, text ="Te pondre música alegre").pack()
      boton1 = Button(nueva, text ="Más", command = alegre1)
      boton1.place(x = 210, y = 40)
      ventana1.withdraw()
      

def alegre1( nueva = Alegre().nueva ):  ### solo se cambio esta linea
      nueva1 = Toplevel(nueva)
      nueva1.title("Interación")
      nueva1.geometry("500x500")
      Label(nueva1, text ="¿Como quieres seguir?").pack()
      boton1 = Button(nueva1, text ="Karaoke", command = karaoke)
      boton1.place(x = 210, y = 40)
      boton1 = Button(nueva1, text ="Videos graciosos", command = karaoke)
      boton1.place(x = 210, y = 70)
      nueva.withdraw()
    
def karaoke():
      nueva2 = Toplevel(ventana1)
      nueva2.title("Interación")
      nueva2.geometry("500x500")
      Label(nueva2, text ="Quieres cerrar").pack()
      boton1 = Button(nueva2, text ="cerrar", command = cerrar)
      boton1.place(x = 210, y = 40) 
      nueva1.withdraw()
    
def cerrar():
      nueva3 = Toplevel(ventana1)
      nueva3.title("Interación")
      nueva3.geometry("500x500")
      Label(nueva3, text ="Adios").pack()
      nueva2.withdraw() 
    
def triste():
    nueva4 = Toplevel(ventana1)
    nueva4.title("Interación")
    nueva4.geometry("500x500")
    Label(nueva4, text ="Te pondre música triste").pack()
    ventana1.withdraw()
    
boton1 = Button(ventana1, text ="Alegre", command = alegre)
boton1.place(x = 210, y = 40)
boton2 = Button(ventana1, text ="Triste", command = triste)
boton2.place(x = 210, y = 80)
    
mainloop()
```

Solo la funcion alegre1 fue modificada
La modificacion a la funcion alegre 1 consiste en acceder a la variable "nueva" contenida en la funcion alegre y que este sea un valor por defecto del parametro nueva que se usara en la funcion alegre1 para cerrar la ventana anterior.

```
def alegre1( nueva = Alegre().nueva ):  ### solo se cambio esta linea
  nueva1 = Toplevel(nueva)
  nueva1.title("Interación")
  nueva1.geometry("500x500")
  Label(nueva1, text ="¿Como quieres seguir?").pack()
  boton1 = Button(nueva1, text ="Karaoke", command = karaoke)
  boton1.place(x = 210, y = 40)
  boton1 = Button(nueva1, text ="Videos graciosos", command = karaoke)
  boton1.place(x = 210, y = 70)
  nueva.withdraw()
```

Te sugiero que aprendas Programacion orientada a objetos para que puedas desarrollar codigos mas faciles de programar y leer

Comment: no me abre el código cuando lo copio

Comment: cual codigo no te abre? la funcion sola o todo el codigo? recuerda incluir el error que entrega la consola en cada una de tus respuestas para facilitar resolver el problema

Comment: todo el codigo que pusistes

Comment: es debido a la identacion extra que le da stack overflow, ya se la elimine, intenta ahora. RECUERDA INDICAR EL ERROR QUE TE ARROJA LA CONSOLA!

Comment: me sale en rojo esta parte del código from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *, y abajo al final me sale esto cuando lo recopilo en python idle SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement. Cuando lo pongo en el block de nota y lo abro me sale la pantalla negra pero después se cierra rapido.

Comment: También recalco que ya lo pude solucionar de una forma que al abrir una ventana y al presionar un boton, lo cierre la ventana anterior y así sucesivamente al presionar un boton. Pero me agrada la forma de ver distintas soluciones con tu código.